# Understanding "Last Dividend Reported" in Bloomberg's database

Tags: dividends, stock-dividend

In Bloomberg's database, there is statistic called "Last Dividend Reported" (see picture below). For the stocks that I looked at, it's usually a number smaller than 1. What exactly is this figure? Is it dividend per share?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is dividend per a share. Without knowing the company or at least the share price it's hard to be more precise.  And each site has their own formula for calculating the various ratios. Bloomberg seems to go off the latest announcement. For example IBM announced Tuesday April 24 that they will raise the quarterly dividend to $1.57 a share. Bloomberg already shows the Last Dividend Reported as $1.57. Yahoo still shows it at $1.50.

What we can't tell from the information you provided is how often the dividend gets paid. Most frequently dividends get paid quarterly. Less frequently they get paid monthly. And occasionally a company will announce a special dividend. Which means they have some extra cash and decide to give it back to shareholders. And some companies will pay a regular dividend and occasionally also pay a special dividend. For example Costco currently pays 50 cents a share quarterly and last May they paid a $7 a share special dividend. I hear they have plans to do something similar this year.

To confuse things more, sometimes the site will assume a quarterly dividend when calculating the yield even if it is a one time special dividend.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is the dividend per share, in dollars (assuming a U.S. stock), usually paid quarterly. For most stocks, if you multiply that number by 4 and divide by the stock price, you will get the dividend yield in the previous line.